# Matlab: passing carriage return from unix to matlab

Tags: matlab, unix, command-line, carriage-return, pid

I am invoking matlab in unix terminal-A with below commandline.

```
matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -r "try;myfunc;end;quit"
```

myfunc.m file has artype = input('Press 1 for add: \n')

I use process ID and pass the input to matlab from a terminal-B using

```
echo "1" > /proc/<processID of MATLAB>/fd/0
```

1 is successfully passed to matlab running in terminal-A. However, since matlab input() expects carriage return to execute next line in .m file. How do I pass carriage return to matlab from unix terminal-B?

Comment: Maybe you  could use an [escape code](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html), like  `echo "1\n" > ...`

Comment: I tried echo "1\n" echo "1\r" echo "1\r\n" these did not work. I think it has to do something with how matlab interprets return as, like char(13). But when I pass char(3) it interprets as string rather than mimicking enter key.

Comment: Two things to try: some linux's want you to add the `-e` flag to echo to get it to interpret backslash sequences.  Or you could try inserting a raw control character `echo "^M"` or `echo "^J"` (control-m is CR and control-j is NL).  To insert the raw control characters, you use control-v followed by what you actually want to insert.